# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - ngIf - hiding/showing progressbar

Tags: angular

I've got my HTTP interceptor to open loading bar each time HTTP request is made:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const dataStorageService = this.injector.get(DataStorageService);
dataStorageService.openProgressbar.next(true);
return next
    .handle(req)
    .do(evt => {
         if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
             dataStorageService.openProgressbar.next(false);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return Observable.throw(err);
    });
}
```

Then in my data-storage-service I have a subject:

```
openProgressbar = new Subject<boolean>();
```

And I listen to it in my app component, where I placed my loading bar:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataStorageService.openProgressbar.subscribe(ifOpen: boolean => {
        this.alertMessageNavbarStatus = ifOpen;
    });
}
```

html:

```
<div id="Intro" *ngIf="alertMessageNavbarStatus">
<app-progress-bar-indeterminate-example>
</app-progress-bar-indeterminate-example>
</div>
```

But the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError is showing. I was looking for solution with using ngAfterContentChecked but it didn't work for me. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

IMO Put your conditional logic into `setTimeout` trick for you, like this -

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataStorageService.openProgressbar.subscribe(ifOpen: boolean => {
        this.alertMessageNavbarStatus = ifOpen;
    });
},0);
```

For more details I would strongly suggest you to read out this article -

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4